# css migration from richfaces 3 to richfaces 4

Tags: css, jsf, migration, richfaces

We are doing an upgrade from RichFaces 3.3.3 to RichFaces 4.2.0. It seems the elements css class names have been changed but I could not find any mapping between the old and new names. There are plenty of custom css rules in our project for rich components so if we can not transform our custom css to the new names, we have to postpone the migration :(

Does anyone know of such mapping table?

Thanks! Pentike

Answer (score 2):

There are all CSS classes documented in the Developer Guide [1]. Although there is no 3.x -> 4.x mapping, it still might be useful.

[1] http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.2.X/4.2.2.Final/Developer_Guide/en-US/html_single/#appe-Developer_Guide-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters